# VoIP PBX development issues

Tags: c#, sdk, voip, ivr, pbx

We’re a stationery wholesaler. In addition to the stationery we’re a supplier of printed matters as well and we’re going to add a packaging materials division this year.

We currently have a two phone lines installed in my Asterisk phone system. Due to the business improvement, we will need three phone lines. What we’re thinking is a VoIP system with three phone numbers (one for the stationery, printed matters and packaging materials). We have broadband Internet connection. We have a variety of calls (ordering, inquiry, quotation, delivery information) related to more different product groups.

Our company has a workforce of 2 sales representatives. They have to accept about 50 incoming calls and the number of outgoing calls equal per day.

My boss is afraid that our sales staff won’t be able to accept each call after opening the third division – and installing the third phone line.

He doesn’t want to replace our Asterisk but he needs some new features like call queuing and voice-mail, but we’d benefit greatly from an IVR menu system, too. He asked me, as an ignorant of VoIP programming, to develop some new functionality like this. The IVR seems the most difficult one. I found a C# solution for this (a short snippet can be seen below):

```
void call_DtmfReceived(object sender, VoIPEventArgs<DtmfInfo> e)  
{  
    DisposeCurrentHandler();  
    switch (e.Item.Signal.Signal)  
    {  
         case 0: break;  
         case 1: TextToSpeech("Product XY has been designed for those software developers who especially interested in VoIP developments. If you prefer .NET programming languages, you might be interested in Product XY."); break;  
         case 2: MP3ToSpeaker(); break;  
    }  
}
```

(Source: [Codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/746512/How-to-build-a-basic-IVR-Interactive-Voice-Respons))

But I’m looking for another solution that makes it possible to add some new menu items without modifying the source code. Does anyone have any useful ideas?

But first there’s a need for a VoIP SDK. I’ve been looking at `Ozeki VoIP SIP SDK for .NET - 2 simultaneous calls`. According to [this page](http://voip-sip-sdk.com/p_125-asterisk-pbx-setup-voip.html) it is compatible with Asterisk. Can anyone tell me if this is a good option for a business such as mine? Is there any other option I should look at?

Any help would be appreciated!

Regards,
Gerard

Answer (score 0):

Asterisk PBX have internal Queue and IVR subsystem

3 call for asterisk is can't be considering any load, unless you running it on portable device like hand watch.

For setup queue you need simple change in dialplan, no need in "develop" somethins.

I recommend you read any availible asterisk book.

Answer (score 0):

The OZEKI SDK has a bug , when making multiply calls for some hours , you will get memory corrupt or 100% CPU problem.
you better try other SDKs like `VAX VOIP` or `Conaito` but first make an autodialer App. and another IVR App. to receive calls, then test the sdk with these two apps. then purchase.